# PHP form giving internal error

Tags: php, forms

My PHP code always returns HTTP/1.1 500 internal server error. This is being accessed from some AJAX code, and is a serperate file. It is most likely something obvious, any help would be appreciated. 
PHP:

```
<?php  
if( isset($_POST) ){  

//form validation vars  
$formok = true;  
$errors = array();  

//submission data  
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$date = date('d/m/Y');  
$time = date('H:i:s');  

//form data  
$fname = $_POST['fname'];  
$lname = $_POST['lname'];     
$aemail = $_POST['aemail'];  
$year = $_POST['year'];  
$position = $_POST['position'];  
$club = $_POST['club'];  

//validate email address is not empty  
if(empty($email)){  
    $formok = false;  
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";  
//validate email address is valid  
}elseif(!filter_var($aemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){  
    $formok = false;  
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";  
}

//send email if all is ok  
if($formok){  
    $headers = "From: " $aemail . "\r\n";
    $headers = "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

    $emailbody = "<p>You have received a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p> 
                  <p><strong>First Name: </strong> {$fname} </p>
                  <p><strong>Last Name: </strong> {$fname} </p>                      
                  <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p> 
                  <p><strong>School Year: </strong> {$year} </p> 
                  <p><strong>Club: </strong> {$club} </p> 
                  <p><strong>Position: </strong> {$position} </p> 
                  <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

    ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from); 

    $sent = mail("name@domaain.co.uk","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers, "-f" . $email_from);  

}  

//what we need to return back to our form  
$returndata = array(  
    'posted_form_data' => array(  
        'fname' => $fname, 
        'lname' => $fname, 
        'aemail' => $aemail,  
        'year' => $year,  
        'position' => $position,  
        'club' => $club  
    ),  
    'form_ok' => $formok,  
    'errors' => $errors  
);  


//if this is not an ajax request  
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){  
    //set session variables  
    session_start();  
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;  

    //redirect back to form  
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);  
 }  
}
?>
```

Comment: Talk to your web host and see if their servers are running okay... usually that is the cause of a 500 error! If everything is okay in the server, look back over your code and make sure you are using functions that are supported by your current php version.

Comment: did you edit your .htaccess file?

Comment: Also something to try: change that `elseif` to an `if`... and check your PHP error logs on your server.

Comment: @pattyd: Usually that *isn't* the cause of a 500 error. It's pretty much always a programming error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With error messages enabled I see:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$aemail' (T_VARIABLE) in file.php on line 33

The typo is here in line 33:

```
$headers = "From: " $aemail . "\r\n";
//                 ^------------------ note the missing point
```

Write:

```
$headers = "From: " . $aemail . "\r\n";
```

Comment: This has helped with the error many thanks, spotted a few more further down! Just to get it to work with the Ajax now.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a php error. Put this to the header of your php file for seeing the error:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Thanks to @bwoebi I can add that exactly in the case of parse errors to display the error text instead of 500 error you should put this to your .htaccess:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```

Comment: using this in a PHP file won't help against parse errors. You should recommend to set this via .htaccess / php.user.ini / php.ini

Comment: It WILL help to determine the error. Unless there is no error reporting, server will output 500 error.

Comment: It will also output a 500 error with this in the file as PHP already has aborted when parsing the file. It never will execute these two lines.